# How can I wrap a template function with another template function (specifically glm::dot)?

Tags: c++, templates, glm-math

I'm using the glm math library, which offers many vector/matrix structs and operations (for use in graphics). It has types for many different vector sizes (`vec2`, `vec3`, `vec4`, etc...) and also a really clean API to do general operations on them, regardless of size (`dot(a,b)`,`length(a)`, etc...).

One function I would like is to determine the "length squared" of a vector (as it's computationally much cheaper to compare lengths this way), which is essentially this function: `float lengthSquared(v) { return glm::dot(v,v); }`

I'd like to create such a function: how might I go about doing it?

The template signature for `dot` is as follows:

```
template <class T, glm::qualifier Q>
T dot(const glm::qua<T,Q> &x, const glm::qua<T,Q> &y)
```

So my best attempt to wrap is is as follows:

```
template <class T, glm::qualifier Q>
T lengthSquared(const glm::qua<T,Q> &x)
{ return glm::dot(x,x); }
```

But I get many errors including `'lengthSquared': no matching overloaded function found` (when calling it with a `vec2`), and `[signature here]: could not deduce template argument for 'const glm::qua<T,Q> &' from 'glm::vec2'`.

I don't really understand how template "qualifiers" work, so I'm flying a bit blind here.

Thanks!

edit: here's the declaration of `vec2`: `typedef glm::vec<2,float,glm::packed_highp> glm::vec2;`
and here's a sample call to `lengthSquared`: `vec2 x = {0.5,0.5}; float ls = lengthSquared(x);`

Comment: Please show the declaration of `vec2`, and the call to `dot`.

Comment: `auto lengthSquared(const auto &v) { return glm::dot(v,v); }`

Comment: @ThomasSablik it isn't allowing the `auto` in the arguments list (`'auto' is not allowed here`)

Comment: That's a c++20 extension, you can just template it.

Comment: What compiler do you use? https://wandbox.org/permlink/pJv7MiRyh74uhQU5 Current GCC and Clang support it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function definition is:

```
template <class T, glm::qualifier Q>
T lengthSquared(const glm::qua<T,Q> &x)
{ return glm::dot(x,x); }
```

but you are calling this function with an argument of type `glm::vec<2,float,glm::packed_highp>`.

Instead, you can write the function like this:

```
template <class T>
auto lengthSquared(const T &x)
{ return glm::dot(x,x); }
```

and let the compiler deduce both the argument type, and the return type.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it seemingly doesn't work for you I post a simple C++20 alternative that is supported by current versions of GCC and Clang:

```
auto lengthSquared(const auto &v) { return glm::dot(v,v); }
```